# new site admin not able to browse categories in wordpress multisite

Tags: multisite, taxonomy

I am working on wordpress multisite. The site i am working on was coded by someone else and made lots of changes in admin. He also made changes in the capabilities and roles. I created an user and a new site and made the user and the admin of the site created. I got an error when i tried this link `http://subdomain.example.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category` it shows me `You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.` I have also added `manage_categories` capability to the user but still i got that error. Can anyone have any idea on this.

Thanks in advance